# Stringify keys error when building a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am getting a `stringify_keys` error.

Currently I am calling the following method which works perfectly:

```
def attributes
  {
    city:         @content[1..20].strip,
    streetname:   @content[21..40].strip,
    house_number: @content[41..46].strip.to_i
  }
end
```

Now that I am refactoring my code, I need to build the hash from the ground up where the keys and values are populating the hash based on certain conditions (conditions are not written yet).

```
def attributes
  test = {}
  test["city"]          = @content[1..20].strip
  test["streetname"]    = @content[21..40].strip
  test["house_number"]  = @content[41..46].strip.to_i
end
```

Now I am getting the `stringify_keys` error. I checked the docs for clues on how to build a hash but there isn't anything that could help me.

Where is the problem? If you need more code, please ask.

Comment: instead `test["city"]` use `test[:city]`.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work either. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: What @Monk_Code said is true, you changed the keys from `Symbol` to `String`. Also, your new method returns the value of `@content[41..46].strip.to_i` (the last value of the method), whereas your old method returns the entire `Hash`. That could cause issues as well. Since your `attributes` returns a `Fixnum`, you might get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'stringify_keys' for Fixnum` because of it. Fix by `return test` or just `test` on the last line of your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is symbol in your first piece of code, and you have to return `test` at last in your second piece of code.

```
def attributes
  test = {}
  test[:city]          = @content[1..20].strip
  test[:streetname]    = @content[21..40].strip
  test[:house_number]  = @content[41..46].strip.to_i
  test
end
```

Comment: Wow thanks, calling `test` on the last line fixed this after already changing the keys from a `string` back to a `symbol`, as stated by @Monk_Code and @Daniël Knippers. Could you explain why calling `test` again is required for it to work?

Comment: @RobinvanDijk `test` at last is same as `return test`, ruby will return last evaluated expression.

Answer (score 1):

In `Rails` with `active support` you can use `symbolize_keys` and `stringify_keys` look example:

```
  => hash = {"foo"  => 1, 'baz' => 13}
  => {"foo"=>1, "baz"=>13}
  => hash.symbolize_keys
  => {:foo=>1, :baz=>13}
```

and back:

```
  => hash.symbolize_keys.stringify_keys
  => {"foo"=>1, "baz"=>13}
```